# Exercise 4.7 Kesavan's book Topics in Functional Analysis and Applications

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Below I present Exercise 4.7 from Kesavan's book [Topics in Fucntional Analysis and Applications](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Topics_in_functional_analysis_and_applic.html?id=mDvvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) chapter 4.

I could solve item (a) but I don't know how to get (b) from (a). I would like some hint or reference.

(a) Let $V$ be a Banach space and $A:D(A)\subset V\to V$ the infinitesimal gererator of a $C_0$-semigroup {$S(t)$} on $V$. If $u\in D(A^2)$, show that 
$$S(t)u-u=tAu+\int_0^t(t-\tau)S(\tau)A^2u\, d\tau.$$

(b) Deduce that for $u\in D(A^2)$,
$$\|Au\|^2\leq 4M^2\|A^2u\|\,\|u\|,$$
if $\|S(t)\|\leq M,$ for all $t.$

**Solution of item (a)**

In order to solve (a) I defined $f(t)=S(t)u$. Since $u\in D(A^2)$ we have that $f\in C^2([0,+\infty);V)$. Also $f'(t)=S(t)Au$  and $f''(t)=S(t)A^2u$. Using [Taylor Formula with integral remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) we have the result for item (a).

Comment: A direct solution for **(a)**, without the application of the Taylor Formula, can be obtained by defining $h(t)=S(t)u-tS(t)Au$ and integrating both sides of $h'=\cdots$ from $0$ to $t$ (after that, it is needed to add and subtract $tAu$).

Comment: Yes, it is true. But what I need is a solution for (b). I have been struggling with it for days.

Comment: I see (and this is why my comment is a "comment" instead of an answer) but, unfortunately, I couldn't solve (b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. After a lot of search, I found out, in this book [A short course on operator semigroups](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387313412) page 45, that this inequality is Know as **Landau–Kolmogorov inequality**. So, it was a question of time until to find the proof in the Lemma 2.8 of the classical book [Pazy. Semigroups of linear operators and applications to partial differential equations.](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=DQvpBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Semigroups%20of%20Linear%20Operators%20and%20Applications%20to%20Partial%20Differential%20.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx5_LG0L3oAhVxFLkGHRNGANoQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Semigroups%20of%20Linear%20Operators%20and%20Applications%20to%20Partial%20Differential%20.&f=false).

For the sake of convenience, I will reproduce the proof here.

From **(a)** we have that
$$Au = \frac{S(t)u-u}{t}+\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t(t-\tau)S(\tau)A^2u\, d\tau,\ \forall t\in (0,+\infty)$$
Hence, for all $t\in (0,+\infty)$, we have that
\begin{align}
\|Au\|& \leq  \frac{1}{t} \big(\|S(t)u\|+\|u\|\big)+\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t(t-\tau)\|S(\tau)A^2u\|\, d\tau\\
& \leq  \frac{1}{t} \big(M\|u\|+\|u\|\big)+\frac{M}{t}\|A^2u\|\int_0^t(t-\tau)\, d\tau\\
& \leq \frac{1}{t}(M+1)\|u\|+\frac{Mt}{2}\|A^2u\|\\
& \leq \frac{2M}{t}\|u\|+\frac{Mt}{2}\|A^2u\|.\ \ \ \ \  \text{($M\geq 1$, since $S(0)=I$.) }
\end{align}
Now, note that the function $f(t)=\frac{a}{t}+bt$ has a minimum $2\sqrt{ab}$ at $t=\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$. Hence, taking $a=2M\|u\|$ and $b=\frac{M}{2}\|A^2u\|$ we have that
$$\|Au\|\leq 2\sqrt{M^2\|A^2u\|\|u\|},$$
whence the result follows.

It is worth to mention that, if we don't use $M\geq 1$, we will actually prove a the following better inequality
$$\|Au\|^2\leq 2(M+1)M\|A^2u\|\|u\|.$$
This proof is found in  [H. Kraljević, S. Kurepa, Semigroups on Banach spaces](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=eMMO854-riYC&pg=PA109&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), Theorem 3.

Comment: It's interesting how the basic idea is surprisingly simple: just isolate the desired term in the given equality and estimate it.

Comment: Yeah. I tried it, but I couldn't realize how choose the right $t$. Thanks for you comments.